# how to validate a text box with Regular Expression Validator?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex

I have tested my regular expression in "rubular" and it is passing all my required conditions.But when i use that into asp text box its not passing true.

My Code looks like below

```
<asp:TextBox ID="MobileNumber" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="MobileNumberValidater" runat="server" ControlToValidate="MobileNumber" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid Numbers"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

My regular expression looks like below

^((0((?=\d* \d*#)[\d ]{,11})(#\d{,5})?)|(0(?:\d{,10})(#\d{,5})?)|(0((?=\d* \d*$)[\d ]{,11})))$

I am trying to validate the following strings:

1).012345 6789#123

2).025698 785#6548

Thanks.

Comment: Here is a useful post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824403/asp-net-regular-expression-validator-client-side-script-error. Ensure "EnableClientScript" is set to false. It might be a good idea to post the server side code aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick check [here](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx) seems to indicate that the regex you are using is incorrectly formatted for the .Net client. I'm not familiar with Rubular, but it may be that it uses a different regex engine.

I had a play with your regex, but those phone numbers don't look like anything I've seen, so if you're stuck it may be worth taking a look [here](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/validate-phone-number).