# How to remove both html tags & content,values inside the tags using regular expressions

Tags: regex

How to remove both html tags & content,values inside the tags using regular expressions

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at some of these articles

- [When is it wise to use
  regular expressions with HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816255/when-is-it-wise-to-use-regular-expressions-with-html)
- [Regex HTML Extraction C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894995/regex-html-extraction-c)

*But be aware, you are opening yourself for a whole world of hurt*.

[Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/)

Answer (score 0):

As generic as your question is, you will probably only get generic answers:

Use an HTML DOM parser.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an html parser for this, e.g. [htmlcleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/)